# EF6 CodeFirst - Dealing with OUTPUT parameters

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I'm trying to consume a stored procedure with EF6/CodeFirst. This SP returns couple of values via OUTPUT parameters. I have seen in [other places](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-entity-framework-code-first-with-stored-procedures-that-have-output-parameters) that this might not be possible, but this article is pretty old and just wondering whether this is solved by now.

My SP when executed with RAW Sql (In SSMS) works like this;

```
    declare @p10 int
    declare @p11 uniqueidentifier
    set @p10=NULL
    set @p11=NULL
    exec dbo.uspTestStoredProc @id = 2021, @name=N'qa1231321asda.txt', 
         @documentId=@p10 OUTPUT,@documentStreamId=@p11 output
    select @p10,@p11
```

This one correctly prints out the documentId (p10) and documentStreamId (p11)

However wWhen executed via EF both of these OUTPUT params are null. I've included both the .Net code and SQL generated via EF below for further investigation.

## .Net Code

```
var sqlString = "exec dbo.uspTestStoredProc @id,@name,@documentId,@documentStreamId";
var paramCollection = new List<Object>
                {
                    new SqlParameter("id", 81),
                    new SqlParameter("name", "qa1231321asda2.txt"),
                };

                var paramDocId = new SqlParameter
                {
                     ParameterName = "@documentId",
                     SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                     Value = 0,
                     Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                };
                paramCollection.Add(paramDocId);

                var paramStreamId = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@documentStreamId",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,
                    Value = DBNull.Value,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                };

paramCollection.Add(paramStreamId);

_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlString, paramCollection.ToArray());

var docId = (int) paramDocId.Value; //Fails because paramDocId is DBNull
```

## SQL generated by EF

```
    declare @p10 int
    declare @p11 uniqueidentifier
    set @p10=NULL
    set @p11=NULL
    exec sp_executesql N'exec dbo.uspTestStoredProc @id,@name,@documentId,@documentStreamId', 
    N'@id int,@name nvarchar(45), @documentId int output,@documentStreamId uniqueidentifier output',
    @id=81,@name=N'qa1231321asda2.txt',@documentId=@p10 output,@documentStreamId=@p11 output
    select @p10, @p11
```

Now here @p10 and @p11 returns NULL.

I'm trying to find out the following

1. Can EF6/CodeFirst support OUTPUT parameters from stored procs?
2. If so, what do I need to do differently?
3. If not, any idea when that feature would be available?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally found the answer. The trick is in the sqlString that you pass in to the command.

```
    var sqlString = "exec dbo.uspTestStoredProc @id,@name,
                     @documentId OUT,@documentStreamId OUT";
```

Notice the keyword 'OUT' after the 2 output parameters. It does the trick. Of course you also need to specify the proper SQL Parameter options like ParameterDirection.Output when adding the parameters.